# Viewpager Fragment 1 onCreateView is not always being called

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragment-lifecycle

When I swipe to or select Fragment1 (Fragment Numbers are 0-3) from its adjacent Fragments(0 , 2) in viewPager its onCreateView, or onCreate function is not being called.

But when I swipe back from Fragment3 or select Fragment1 when Fragment3 is active then both of these functions are being called. I am confused about why not from the adjacent Fragments its being called.

this is the code of Fragment who's onCreateView is not being called properly

`public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

```
ShimmerFrameLayout shimmerFrameLayout ;
ConstraintLayout contentLayout;

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "US News", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.d("Called", "onCreate: ");
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.us_news_fragment_layout , container , false);
    shimmerFrameLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.usNewsShimmerLayoutId);
    contentLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.usNewsLayoutId);

    shimmerFrameLayout.startShimmerAnimation();

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           shimmerFrameLayout.stopShimmerAnimation();
           shimmerFrameLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
           contentLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    },3000);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    Log.d("USNews", "onCreateView: ");
}
```

}`

This is the code in the main Activity for handling the events related to the viewpager

```
 viewPager = findViewById(R.id.homeViewPagerId);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Home"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("US News"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Politics"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Live"));
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            int position = tab.getPosition();
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });

    homePagerAdapter = new HomePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager() , tabLayout.getTabCount());
    viewPager.setAdapter(homePagerAdapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
```

//                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, String.valueOf(tabLayout.getTabAt(position).getText()) + " is Active Now", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
homePagerAdapter.getItem(position);
}

```
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            homePagerAdapter.getItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });

    homePagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

And this is the adapter of the ViewPager i am using

```
public class HomePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
int NUM_OF_TABS;
private String[] tabTitles = new String[]{"Home", "US News", "Politics" , "Live"};
public HomePagerAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fm , int numberOfTabs) {
    super(fm);
    this.NUM_OF_TABS = numberOfTabs;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return tabTitles[position];
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position){
        case 0:
            Fragment0 homeFragment = new Fragment0 ();
            return  homeFragment;
        case 1:
            Fragment1 usNewsFragment = new Fragment1 ();
            return usNewsFragment;
        case 2:
            Fragment2 politicsFragment = new Fragment2 ();
            return politicsFragment;
        case 3:
            Fragment3 liveFragment = new Fragment3 ();
            return  liveFragment;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return NUM_OF_TABS;
}
```

}

Please assist me about this. I'll be very thankful to you.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

maybe this layout is already created and drawn? `ViewPager` have some handy option - keeps at least two additional `View`s/`Fragment`s in memory for fast switching between pages. you can change this value to some higher only by calling [setOffscreenPageLimit](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/viewpager/widget/ViewPager#setoffscreenpagelimit). by default its set to 1 - means that `ViewPager` keeps up to 3 `Fragment`s - one to the left, one to the right and one currently visible on screen. with finger fling UI can just slide left/right page without drawing it from scratch (making almost always some small glitch/hang)

I bet you have two `onCreate` calls on start of your `Activity` - `Fragment0`s and `Fragment1`s. when you switch to `Fragment1` you will see `Fragment2` log, as `ViewPager` will prepare it for potential next swipe-left gesture. you can always use `setOffscreenPageLimit(Integer.MAX_VALUE);` for forcing all `Fragment`s to be drawn at start and kept in memory (but only if these `Fragment`s aren't to heavy, according to your tab names they might be...)

also `homePagerAdapter.getItem(position);` call in `onPageSelected` and `onPageScrolled` is unnecessary - it is creating new `Frament` and returning it, thats all, it isn't used. thats `ViewPager`s job to call this method (from attached adapter), take this `Fragment` and draw (on the screen or just render in memory for potential future use when user swipe left/right)

Comment: As @snachmsm has said viewpager caches Fragments and thus does not have to create/recreate them always when moving between fragments thus `onCreateView` does not also need to be called when moving between fragments. If you want to do something when a fragment comes on to screen then with a recent viewpager version (or configured to do so) the viewpager will `pause` offscreen fragments and only `resume` the current fragement thus you can do things in the fragments `onResumed` method

Comment: First of all thanks for you response. I've tried to setOffscreenPageLimit(int limit) from 0 to 3 but the problem persists. 

you are saying it right that when i swipe to the Fragment 1 the oncreateview of Fragment2 is being called and wise versa. 

But how do I resolve it that the onCreateView of the current fragment is called ?

Comment: it was called proviously/earlier, when this `Fragment` was really created (before it gets visible). just try to understand this mechanism and fit into it, max pages can't be lower than 1. just don't assume that `onCreateView` is called when your `Fragment` is entering into screen, it may not and `ViewPager` patterns proofing that

Comment: What if I want to do a specific task(I.e. a http request) whenever user enter the Fragment Screen. 

Which Function I have to use then ?

Comment: use `OnPageChangeListener` - it will inform you which `Fragment` is currently visible. e.g. track `state` from `onPageScrollStateChanged` - when it change to `SCROLL_STATE_IDLE` (previous value of `state` wasn't idle) then send your request basing on `getCurrentItem()` position

Comment: "What if I want to do a specific task(I.e. a http request) whenever user enter the Fragment Screen." as I said in my previous comment put this specific task in the `onResumed` method of your Fragment As you should be constructing you adaptor with `BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT ` now see https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter#FragmentStatePagerAdapter(androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager,%20int) as everything else is deprecated. This is better than a `OnPageChangeListener`

Comment: I can agree only "blindly" as I never used `BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT`, its pretty new flag. but can agree that this approach may be better, looks like introduced exacly for OPs case

Comment: The `BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT` flag is now the default in current versions of viewpager I believe and is now only the non deprecated method. It also makes viewpager be compatible with viewpager2's behaviour. It also does not break the concept of a Fragment and it's lifecycle. (Also an `OnPageChangeListener` will triggers at some point during the transition between the 2 fragments there is no guarantees on exact timing, where as `onResume` in the Fragment only happens when the Fragment is fully on screen)